# Swift UICollectionView : didSelectItemAtIndexPath not responding

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xcode7.3, ios9.3

i have UICollection view in a ViewController and it's not responding to didSelectItemAtIndexPath at all.

```
// super class
class ViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDelegate, iCarouselDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


// delegate
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // collection view delegate and datasource
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self


// did select item
        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

           print(indexPath)

        }
```

and this delegate from IB . 
[image: UiCollectionView delegate in IB]

Comment: Hey, May I know is there any button in cell. Or what is the content of customCell?

Comment: when i posted question i had no buttons , just image and label.

now i have answered this question with how i solved this issue .

Go check my answer

Answer (score 3):

several guesses might be helpful:

- did you accidentally overriding `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`?
- make sure set `collectionView.userInteractionEnabled` to true
- if some high priority `UIResponder` like `UIGestureRecognizer` and `UIButton` added to cell or its subview, corresponding method should be call instead

Comment: i have an ICarousel in same viewController , may mb this the reason ? @Chen Wei

Comment: No, did you connect that '@IBOutlet collectionview' to the collection view in storyboard? If so the name in screenshot should be the same with variable "collectionview" rather than the default name "Collection View"

Comment: i did connect IBOutlet collectionview @Chen Wei , and thanks at all . 

i solved my problem in another way .. i'm going to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

i had to use another way to run away from this issue and ship my project in time.

i made a button inside my cell and in this method "cellForItemAtIndexPath" and added target for it like so:

```
imageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.imageButtonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

and passed the selected indexPath.row in this button tag like so :

```
imageButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

and this my Action :

```
func imageButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

let categoryId = categories[sender.tag]["id"]
    let categoryName = categories[sender.tag]["category_name"]

    let mainCategory = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainCategoryViewController") as! MainCategoryViewController
    mainCategory.mainCategoryId = categoryId!
    mainCategory.title = categoryName!
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(mainCategory, animated: true)

}
```